# Google's URL encoding?

Tags: url

I have noticed that Google does not encode all special characters in the query part of the URL . For example:

```
Placing this string in Google's search: !@#$%^&*()

Yields this URL: https://www.google.com/#q=!%40%23%24%25^%26*()
```

Notice that the !, ^, *, ( , and ) are not encoded.

Some of the characters such as : or < are considered unsafe or reserved, yet Google doesn't encode them.

Can someone explain why Google does this, and if they have a reference document as to exactly what characters get encoded and which don't?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I see no direct connection to programming here.

Comment: ¨ is not encoded neither

Comment: I would like to know as I am writing a script that generates Google URL's, and want to make sure I'm including the correct encoding.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just encode everything. It gets decoded anyway. Or encode nothing, as the browser will handle it for you anyway.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes, that's true, but I would like to shorten my URL's as much as possible since they are Google specific. I only want to encode what is absolutely necessary. Some of my URL's contain foreign characters which make the encoded URL really long.

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results_appendices?hl=en#url-escaping):

> Some characters are not safe to use in a URL without first being
> encoded. Because a Google search request is made by using an HTTP URL,
> the search request must follow URL conventions, including character
> encoding, where necessary.
>
> The HTTP URL syntax defines that only alphanumeric characters, the
> special characters $-_.+!*'(), and the reserved characters ;/?:@=& can
> be used as values within an HTTP URL request. Since reserved
> characters are used by the search engine to decode the URL, and some
> special characters are used to request search features, then all
> non-alphanumeric characters used as a value to an input parameter must
> be URL-encoded.
>
> To URL-encode a string:
>
> Replace space characters with a "+" character Replace each
> non-alphanumeric character by its hexadecimal ASCII value, in the
> format of a "%" character followed by two hexadecimal digits. (Such an
> ASCII value may be referred to as an escape code.)
>
> Some input parameters require that the values passed to Google search are double-URL-encoded. This requirement means that you must apply the URL encoding to the string twice in succession to generate the final value.

Comment: They don't seem to stick to their own standard. In their reference document they make an example of this string: admission form site:www.stanford.edu which should yield this encoded result: admission+form+site%3Awww.stanford.edu However, when I use that same string in my browser, the corresponding google URL is: https://www.google.com/#q=admission+form+site:www.stanford.edu - The colon never gets encoded

Comment: @Josh I can't confirm you. Because the encoded query string for me is `q=admission+form+site%3Awww.stanford.edu`

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! Unfortunately, I've tried with three different browsers and am getting the same result.